# How to add a different kernel for each version of Julia in Jupyter

Tags: kernel, julia, version, jupyter

I have several version of Julia on my machine for which I created an alias in my `bash_profile` as follows:

```
# Setting Path for Julia
alias julia1.0="/Applications/Julia-1.0.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia"
alias julia1.1="/Applications/Julia-1.1.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia"
alias julia1.2="/Applications/Julia-1.2.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia"
```

and in each of the version them, I ran the command:

```
using Pkg; Pkg.add("IJulia")
```

which didn't throw any error for any of the version, but it didn't add any new julia kernel in `Jupyter`

How can I successfully add a Kernel for each of the Julia version?

N.B., there is a fourth alias, namely `julia` which opens `Julia 1.1`, if that might help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run the package's build step first, that's what installs the kernel. Run

```
]build IJulia
```

in each of your Julia instances.